# Does preventDefault() in keydown event prevent a following keypress event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html page with a webgl canvas and javascript attached. In the script i listen to 'keydown', 'keypress' and 'keyup' events of the canvas. Inside the eventhandlers i log to debug when the events are triggered. If i call preventDefault() on the event object in the 'keydown' handler i don't get 'keypress' events anymore and wonder if this is intended behavior? So if i press for example a character key like 'a', the keydown and keyup events are fired, but keypress is only called if i preventDefault() is not called in the keydown event handler.

I tested this on windows, firefox and chrome so far.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Main</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <style>
        body,html { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:black; width:100%; height:100%; }
        canvas#webgl { width:100%; height:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="webgl" tabindex="0"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test_canvaskeypress.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test_canvaskeypress.js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("webgl"); 
canvas.addEventListener('keydown',this.onKeyDown,false);
canvas.addEventListener('keyup',this.onKeyUp,false);
canvas.addEventListener('keypress',this.onKeyPress,false);


function onKeyDown(e) {
    console.log('keyup: '+e.keyCode); 
    e.preventDefault();//prevents the keypress event, is this intended behavior?
    e.stopPropagation();

}
function onKeyUp(e) {
    console.log('keydown: '+e.keyCode); 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
function onKeyPress(e) {
    console.log('keypress: '+e.key); 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I don't know what to expect, because the docs for preventDefault are not very informative, but i think a keypress event should appear nonetheless preventDefault is called in onKeyDown(), because the key up event also is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the most recent W3C Working Draft (https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#keydown) we can see that one of the keydown default actions is the keypress event (among others)! So, when you do a preventDefault on the keydown event, you are actually preventing the event default actions, and in this case, one of those actions is the keypress event.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a similar issue.

I was trying to prevent the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> from causing the page to scroll.

I added `preventDefault` to all key events to prevent the page scrolling. It worked, but it also stopped the `keypressed` event from firing. I needed this event elsewhere, so I had to find a work around.

It turns out that the scroll action that the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> performs is triggered by the `keypressed` event.

To solve the problem I called `preventDefault` only on the `keypressed` event. I left the `keyup` and `keydown` events untouched.

Just wanted to share this in case someone in my situation stumbles upon this page.

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event

So, If you want all the three methods to get fired remove `stopPropagation()` from all the three events. Hope it will work.

Comment: Tested it real quick and it does not work, PreventDefault still prevents the keypress event. And by the way, i dont want my events to bubble up the dom tree. And i think propagating event upwards is not needed here, because all my eventhandlers are bound to canvas and no parent elements.