# JS keydown + keypress + preventDefault

Tags: javascript, events

What we have:

1. `keydown` event + `preventDefault` prevents `keypress` event (proof: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401334/9398364)
2. `stopPropagation` doesn't help at all
3. We can't simulate keypress with dispatchEvent because we don't know full list of unprintable `event.key` values (which we can't just throw as unicode value using `event.key.codePointAt(0)`)

What we need:

1. Disable default browser keys reaction (i.e. `tab` press in chrome) without huge switch expression
2. Detect `keydown` events because we need `shift`, `ctrl` and other keys events
   (`event.code` matters)
3. Detect `keypress` events because we need to input unicode characters (`event.key` matters) without `input` event **and** without checking if it is unprintable character (such as `shift` and `ctrl`)

How?

UPD:
Seems like non-unicode event.key has >1 length (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401792/9398364)
Is there any proof?

Comment: Maybe test that keydown is a useful key for your application using a regex (ex: `/\w|\d|ctrl|shift/`), else `preventDefault()` ?

Comment: @JeanWill that's too dirty and slow solution even if it works. I need all the keys ever existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

```js
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event)
        {
            onKeyboard(event.code);
            if (event.key.length === 1 && !event.ctrlKey && !event.metaKey)
            {
                const utf16Code = event.key.codePointAt(0);
                onKeyboardInput(utf16Code);
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }, false);
```